# Удаление Apache2

Tags: apache, linux

Собственно вопрос: попытался удалить апач.

```
apt-get remove apache2
```

Но возникла ошибка, теперь апач не запускается

> `root@194:/etc# service apache2 start
>  * Starting web server apache2
>  apache2: Syntax error on line 203 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Include directory
>  'mods-enabled' not found
>                                                                          [fail])`

Директория есть. При попытке удалить апач (`apt-get remove apache2`)

> `The following packages will be REMOVED:
>   apache2
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
> After this operation, 36.9kB disk space will be freed.
> Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
> (Reading database ... 48868 files and directories currently installed.)
> Removing apache2 ...
> root@194:/etc#`

При попытке установить (`apt-get install apache2`)

> `The following NEW packages will be installed:
>   apache2
> 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
> Need to get 0B/1,486B of archives.
> After this operation, 36.9kB of additional disk space will be used.
> Selecting previously deselected package apache2.
> (Reading database ... 48866 files and directories currently installed.)
> Unpacking apache2 (from .../apache2_2.2.14-5ubuntu8.7_i386.deb) ...
> Setting up apache2 (2.2.14-5ubuntu8.7) ...
> root@194:/etc#`

Прошу помощи.

**Добавлено.**

```
root@194:/etc# apt-get purge apache2
```

> `Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> Package apache2 is not installed, so not removed
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
> 2.root@194:/etc# apt-get clean
> 3.root@194:/etc# apt-get install apache2
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
>   apache2
> 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
> Need to get 1,486B of archives.
> Setting up apache2 (2.2.14-5ubuntu8.7) ...`

Результата нет.

Comment: "Собственно вопрос попытался: удалить апач. (apt-get remove apache2) Но возникла ошибка, теперь апач не запускается"

Ржом всем офисом :) 

P.S. apt-get remove apache2 --pugre
apt-get clean
apt-get install apache2

Comment: Какая сейчас ошибка?

Comment: Такая же как в 1 посте.

Comment: Полностью приведите путь к директории

И путь к конфигу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена.

1. `sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2-utils`
2. `sudo apt-get install apache2`

Всем спасибо.