# Apache2 не запускается

Tags: linux, apache

Хотел поставить PHPMYADMIN, нашёл инструкцию, но не получилось. Apache2 перестал запускаться. После этого я решил удалить все файлы PHPMYADMIN, попробовал запустить apache, выдаёт ошибку:

```
May 27 11:28:16  apachectl[1085]: apache2: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: No such file or directory
May 27 11:28:16  apachectl[1085]: Action 'start' failed.
May 27 11:28:16  apachectl[1085]: The Apache error log may have more information.
May 27 11:28:16  systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 27 11:28:16 v125933 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 27 11:28:16 v125933 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Что делать?

Comment: Он точно вам пишет, что происходит. Он не может найти свой конфигурационный файл /etc/apache2/apache2.conf Куда он мог деться никто не скажет, вам виднее, что вы делали с своей системой. Если файл не найдется то надо переустановить апач

Comment: Я уже переустанавливал. Он его не генерирует

Comment: Помогла эта тема https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/72102/Удаление-apache2?rq=1. Надо было всё от него снести